# OneToOneField and Deleting

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

When using the Django admin to delete the user, the profile gets deleted as well, which is what I want. However, when using the Django admin to delete the profile, the user does *not* get deleted, which is *not* what I want. How can I make it so that deleting the profile will also delete the user?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Since `Profile` links to `User`, it is the dependent model in the relationship. Therefore when you delete a user, it deletes all dependent models. However when you delete a profile, since `User` does not depend on profile, it is not removed.

Unfortunately, according to `on_delete` Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete), there is no `on_delete` rule which deletes the parent relations. In order to do that, you can overwrite the `Profile`'s `delete` method:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # ...

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user.delete()
        return super(self.__class__, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then when doing:

```
Profile.objects.get(...).delete()
```

will also delete the profile's user. However the `delete` method will not be called when deleting profiles using querysets (which is what is called in Django Admin) since then Django uses SQL DELETE to delete objects in bulk:

```
Profile.objects.filter(...).delete()
```

In that case, as recommended by Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.delete), you will have to use `post_delete` signal ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_delete)).

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Profile)
def post_delete_user(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.user: # just in case user is not specified
        instance.user.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm still new at Django, so in case any other Django noobs find this, I had to add a dispatch_uid to the @receiver decorator in order for it to work. But after that, it worked great!

Comment: @Nick can you elaborate on your solution with dispatch_uid, because with deletion of a bulk of users it doesn't work

Comment: will the signal be called when using the dropdown "delete" action, in a change list? yes it does!

Answer (score 15):

Use a signal on the `Profile`'s delete method to go and delete the related User:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete

def delete_related_user(sender, **kwargs):
    deleted_profile = kwargs['instance']
    deleted_profile.user.delete()

post_delete.connect(delete_related_user, sender=Profile)
```