# django models - invalid data after deleting attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have these model for example (now noses have names):

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Nose(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.OneToOneField('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=False, related_name='nose')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

And I have this code that deletes a person nose (horrible accident...):

```
danny = Person()
danny.save()

# danny.nose would raise: {RelatedObjectDoesNotExist}Person has no nose.

nose = Nose(owner=danny, name='Big one')
nose.save()

# Now data in 'danny' is: 
# "id" attribute: 1
# "nose" attribute: nose instance with name "Big one" and id 1
# danny.nose would return the nose instance

if hasattr(danny, 'nose'):
    danny.nose.delete()

# After delete: data in 'danny': 
# id = 1
# nose: nose instance with name "Big one" and id None
# danny.nose would return the nose instance with None id

danny_from_db = Person.objects.filter(id=1).first()
# data in danny_from_db: id = 1, no "nose" attribute - hasattr(danny, 'nose') would return False
# danny_from_db.nose would raise: {RelatedObjectDoesNotExist}Person has no nose.
```

Why does the `Person` instance keeps that `Nose` attribute with `None` id, after deleting it from DB?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12754229/541277

Comment: @themanatuf Different issue.

Comment: `danny_from_db = Person.filter(id=1).first()` is wrong. Would be: `danny_from_db = Person.objects.filter(id=1).first()`  And for delete issue: Look you are actually deleting the nose entity related with the person instance. not the Person instance. SO it says:   appname.models.Person.nose.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Person has no nose.

Comment: @IqbalHussain sorry it's my mistake. It's `Person.objects.filter(id=1).first()`. That is not the problem that I have in my code.